# Relational Objects - Lazyloading - Best practice?

Tags: php, lazy-loading, separation-of-concerns

I have a `product` object which has a one-to-many relational `price` object. ( one for every country ) I use a repository class to fetch the price objects.
Now I see two "different" approaches on how to get the product price, in a view for example.

1) Lazyloading the price inside the `product` object

```
$productPrice = $product->getPrice('de'); // 'de' representing the country
```

2) Or simply by using the repository directly

```
$productPrice = $priceRepository->filterByProduct($product)->filterByCountry('de')->get();
```

In the first approach, it is the `product` class that basically does the same as 2). So both approaches are very similar.
I have to say that I tend to solution 2), I think it is better separation of concern, and this makes the `product` independent from the price repository.
( although I use a dependency injection container, so it wouldn't be much of a problem )

But what is the best practice here ? ( and for all other relational object for that matter )

Comment: First option certainly looks nicer.

Comment: Yes and No. 1) looks nicer here, but the product class definetly looks nicer in 2) - no dependency, no lazyloading, no 'price' logic at all.

Comment: Answered Your Own question then.  No? 

Comment: Kind of. But I wonder if I will ran into problems with that approach I haven't thought of yet ?